# Why is the contents of the vector being printed wrong here?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int test=0;
    vector<int>v{1,2,3};
    for(auto i=v.cbegin();i!=v.cend();++i)
    {
        ++test;
        if(test==2)
        {
            v.push_back(4);
        }
        cout<<*i<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the output to be only `1 2 3 4` but I received the output as shown below:

[image]

Comment: `v.push_back(4);` *invalidates* the iterator (in case the contents of the vector need to be moved, which is probably the case here), meaning that everything afterwards is invoking *undefined behavior*

Comment: You are changing the vector while iterating through it? That's a weird idea.

Comment: I wanted to test out what would happen if I were to do the same but the output was unexpected hence the question.

Comment: Please post the text output rather than in a separate image (the image could be invalidated over time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The push_back can change the begin and end iterators if the new item doesn't fit in the vector-capacity (the internal size). In your example the push_back implies a reallocation of the internal buffer and the begin and end iterators get new values. The problem in your example is the end-iterator will be evaluated for each step and it gets the new value but the begin Iterator is still keeping the old(invalid) value and that causes undefined behavior.
Following changes will illustrate what happens:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int test=0;
    vector<int>v{1,2,3};
    for(auto i=v.cbegin();i!=v.cend();++i)
    {
        ++test;
        if(test==2)
        {
            std::cout << &*v.cbegin()<<std::endl;
            std::cout << &*v.cend()<<std::endl;
            v.push_back(4);
            std::cout << &*v.cbegin()<<std::endl;
            std::cout << &*v.cend()<<std::endl;
        }
        cout<<*i<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the begin and end iterators changes completely

[show result](http://cpp.sh/6gsyz)

Comment: Note that `push_back()` invalidates existing non-end iterators only if the underlying array has to be reallocated (when the new `size()` would exceed the current `capacity()`).

Comment: my point was, the statement "*The push_back changes the begin and end iterator*" is a little misleading.  It *MAY* change the `begin` iterator, or it *MAY NOT*. It depends on the current `size` and `capacity` of the vector at the time `push_back()` is called.  It *WILL* change the `end` iterator, though, since it is inserting at the end of the vector.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I agree with you and I updated the answer